# Calculus: Help with interpreting problem

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I am currently working on implicit differentiation, and I am stuck with interpreting what specifically "***in exactly one other point***" means. Does this literally mean showing the derivative, or is there something that I am completely missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is the problem verbatim:**

> Show that at every point except for $(x,y) = (0,0), (\pm1,0)$, the tangent line to the curve $y^2 = x^3 - x$ meets the curve **in exactly one other point**.

Thank you very much to anyone who is willing to help me interpret this question.

Comment: They mean that for a general point $P$ on that curve other than those three points, the tangent line to the curve at $P$ intersects the curve in exactly one other point. So (a) you need to find the slope of the curve at $P$, (b) construct the tangent line, and (c) show that the line intersects the curve at exactly two points, one of them $P$, except when $P$ is either $(0,0)$ or $(\pm1, 0)$.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help! I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It may be instructive to look at Diagram $2$ in the "group law" section of the Wikipedia plot summary for [elliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law). (This is in fact an elliptic curve, something which may not mean a whole lot to you—or it might, I suppose—but it is probably the motivation behind this particular question.)

Comment: OK, I'll put my first comment in as a community wiki answer.

Comment: That is super cool! Thank you again for your help. That does mean a lot to me.

Answer (score 1):

They mean that for a general point $P$ on that curve other than those three points, the tangent line to the curve at $P$ intersects the curve in exactly one other point. So, you need to (a) find the slope of the curve at $P$, (b) construct the tangent line, and (c) show that the line intersects the curve at exactly two points, one of them $P$—except when $P$ is either $(0,0)$ or $(\pm1, 0)$.

It may be instructive to look at Diagram $2$ in the "group law" section of the Wikipedia plot summary for [elliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law). This problem is in fact about an elliptic curve, and is probably motivated by that.